# Pack file with tar.gz from root directory

Tags: tar, gzip

I try to pack a .csv file with tar.gz, while being in the root directory.

The file `myfile.csv` is located at `/mnt/sdb1/`
So the full filename is `/mnt/sdb1/myfile.csv`

I try to save the tar.gz under `/mnt/sdb1/old_files`

I tried it like this:

```
tar -czf /mnt/sdb1/old_files/new.tar.gz mnt/sdb1/myfile.csv
```

But when i extract the file, then a folder with name "mnt" will be extracted which cointains another folder called "sdb1", which contains the file.

Is it possible to compress the file only, instead of copying all the directories?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the `--directory` option from `man tar` :

> -C,- -directory DIR
>
> change to directory DIR

i.e.:

```
tar -C /mnt/sdb1/ -czf /mnt/sdb1/old_files/new.tar.gz myfile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you Fiximan! This solved the problem. I will upvote as soon i have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

You have first to `cd /mnt/sdb1`, then launch the `tar` command.

FYI, you don't need to use `tar`here as its purpose is to agglomerate several files in a tarball.  Since you have only one file here, just use `gzip`.

Comment: I know, but i have to do it from the root directory, because i execute the command from a script.

Comment: Man, so just add the `cd` command before `tar`, then you can go back, or use `cd /mnt/sdb1 && tar -czf new.tar.gz myfile.csv && cd /` if you prefer one line cmd.

Comment: @McSinyx The problem is that the directory is not saved, even when i execute `cd /mnt/sdb1/` then i will be in the root directory again at the next execution of a command. But your second solution looks logical to me, i try it.

Comment: @McSinyx NICE! It works :) Thank you, this will be VERY usefull!

Comment: @EdwardBlack You can run a script from anywhere, just add the relevant absolute paths.  In general, using relative paths is a bad idea as it can break things easily.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-C` option to tar:

> ```
>    -C Directory
>         Causes the tar command to perform a chdir subroutine to the
>         directory specified by the Directory variable.
> ```